# Why is VBA not recognising my sheet name? Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro which filters an export from our database, copying the filtered results to different sheets and then copying data from those new sheets across to another workbook for further processing. I have been using code from SO which has worked, but now I am trying to combine the two elements (filtering to new sheets, copy to workbooks) I am encountering some problems which as a newbie I haven't been able to solve!

Everytime I run the macro, I get a 'Subscript out of range' error on this line:

```
Set NAVImperial = NAVExport.Sheets("ROMAN IMPERIAL")
```

Even though there is definitely a worksheet with this name. Is this something to do with the use of ThisWorkbook?

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Sortcodingv2()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim last As Long
Dim sht As String

'specify sheet name in which the data is stored
sht = "236"

'change filter column in the following code
last = Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Sheets(sht).Range("A1:O" & last)

Sheets(sht).Range("C1:C" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("AA1"), Unique:=True

For Each x In Range([AA2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp))
With rng
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=x.Value
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
ActiveSheet.Paste
End With
Next x

' Turn off filter
Sheets(sht).AutoFilterMode = False

With Application
.CutCopyMode = False
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With


Dim NAVExport As Workbook
Set NAVExport = ThisWorkbook


' Roman Imperial
Dim NAVImperial As Worksheet
Dim LIVEImperial As Workbook
Dim LIVEImperialSheet As Worksheet

Dim UniqueIDs As Range
Dim Descriptions As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set NAVImperial = NAVExport.Sheets("ROMAN IMPERIAL")
Set LIVEImperial = Workbooks.Open("\\WDMYCLOUDEX2\Public\Sortcoding\Roman Imperial.xlsm")
Set LIVEImperialSheet = LIVEImperial.Sheets("LIVE Data")

With NAVImperial
  LastRow = NAVImperial.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set UniqueIDs = NAVImperial.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
Set Descriptions = NAVImperial.Range("F2:F" & LastRow)

UniqueIDs.Copy
LIVEImperialSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Descriptions.Copy
LIVEImperialSheet.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

LIVEImperialSheet.Range("C2:O" & LastRow).FillDown

LIVEImperial.Close True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: As a test, try NAVExport = activeWorkbook.Name

Then on down, Workbooks(NAVExport).Sheets("ROMAN IMPERIAL")

I tend to not use "set" and use the names directly (or indirectly via "Sheets(sheetName1)" where sheetName1 = "ROMAN IMPERIAL"). But that could be bad practice on my part!

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook with the code in it - is that what you meant?

Comment: Definitely "ROMAN IMPERIAL" and not " ROMAN IMPERIAL  "? (extra spaces)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is likely that the names don't exactly match, which is why I prefer to avoid Sheets("Name") whenever I can.

If NAVExport is `ThisWorkbook` then all of its sheets are able to be referenced using their  project names, avoiding the use of `Sheets("Name")`. If you open the Project Explorer (Ctrl+R). You should see a list of worksheets under Microsoft Excel Objects. The default names are Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, etc. Find the one with the name in brackets as ROMAN IMPERIAL and that is the sheet you want to reference.

Then, when writing your code, you can directly write `Sheet1.Cells(...` or `Sheet1.Range(...` and you don't need to write `Sheets("ROMAN IMPERIAL")` anymore.

[image: Project Explorer View]